# How to use view modifiers only available for iOS 14+ with deployment target of iOS 13

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios14

How can you add a view modifier to a view when it's only available on iOS 14 but your app is available for iOS 13?

For an example, `textCase(_)`. Section headers in iOS 14 are uppercase so to use the case of your header text you should set `.textCase(.none)` on your `Text`, but this didn't exist until iOS 14.

```
Section(header:
    Text("Header")
        .textCase(.none) //FIXME: 'textCase' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer
        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        .padding(.top, 50)
)
```

Xcode offers some suggestions:

- Add if #available version check
- Add @available attribute

If you use the #available version check, it wraps all of that scoped code with #available, so you'd have to duplicate all of that to add that one line of code. If you use @available you have to duplicate the entire body property or entire struct.

I considered creating my own ViewModifier that would only apply it if iOS 14 but that gives this dreaded error:

> Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in
> its body do not have matching underlying types

```
struct CompatibleTextCaseModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            return content
                .textCase(.none)
        } else {
            return content
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mark `body` as `@ViewBuilder` - this will allow track internal different return types automatically, and remove `return` because explicit return disables view builder wrapper.

So here is fixed variant

```
struct CompatibleTextCaseModifier: ViewModifier {

    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            content
                .textCase(.none)
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}
```

and usage

```
Section(header:
    Text("Header")
        .modifier(CompatibleTextCaseModifier())
        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        .padding(.top, 50)
) {
    Text("test")
}
```

Comment: This solution worked to silence the error but would remove the header for me in iOS 13.  To fix it I replaced the if #available with a guard #available (and flipped the cases) and it worked great!

Comment: Nevermind the guard doesn’t work in iOS 14.  Any advice on this would be awesome.

Comment: This solution is perfect for simple cases like this, but what if you have a big project with tens or hundreds of view modifiers that are only available in iOS 14, creating a compatible modifier for each case will be daunting and you will send up with weird view modifier names, I've created a new question for this regard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68892142/swiftui-using-view-modifiers-between-different-ios-versions-without-available

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here's a very useful extension for View that works for all versions of Swift that support `#available()`:

```
extension View {
    func complexModifier<V: View>(@ViewBuilder _ closure: (Self) -> V) -> some View {
        closure(self)
    }
}
```

And here's how you'd use it:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(/* ... */) { item in
            /* ... */
        }
        .complexModifier {
            if #available(iOS 15, *) {
                $0.listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
            else {
                $0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will set the `.listRowSeparator()` view modifier for the list for users running iOS 15+ only.

It looks like a hack. It sounds a hack. And guest what? It **is** a hack. But it works.