SwiftUI Extension for widgetAccentable()
On a widget, I am trying to make sure the widgets are compatible with the 'Accented' widget rendering mode. Example:
Rectangle() 
 .fill(Color.white)
 .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 0.5, alignment: .top)
 .position(x: geo.size.width/2, y: geo.size.height - 36)
 .widgetAccentable(true)

I inserted the last command:
.widgetAccentable(true)

However, this is only compatible with iOS 16 or newer, asking me to do this to the whole struct:
@available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *)

I have to put .widgetAccentable(true) everywhere and do not want to write two different structs. Is there a way to write an extension for .widgetAccentable() which checks the OS version within and have just one struct?

I find this method to be quite useful, should work in this case too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71203870/15032340

That actually worked!

This worked.
extension View {
 func makeAccentable() -> some View  {
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *) {
            return self.widgetAccentable(true)
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
 }

Use:
Rectangle() 
 .makeAccentable()

