# SwiftUI: use 'accessibilityIdentifier' only on iOS 14+

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Given the following code:

```
struct CopyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    init() {}

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        let copyIconSize: CGFloat = 24
        return Image(systemName: "doc.on.doc")
            .renderingMode(.template)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: copyIconSize, height: copyIconSize)
            .accessibilityIdentifier("copy_button")
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1)
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> 'accessibilityIdentifier' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer use
> on iOS 14

When looking at the `accessibilityIdentifier` declaration, I found this:

```
public func accessibilityIdentifier(_ identifier: String) -> ModifiedContent<Self, AccessibilityAttachmentModifier>
```

Xcode suggest enclosing either the whole button style struct or at least the `makeBody` function to make it available on iOS 14+.

Is there a way to create an additional function, e.g.:

```
func addAccessibilityIdentifierIfAvailable(entryParam ??) -> some View
```

or similar that will return just the same view if the `accessibilityIdentifier` is not available or return a view with the set identifier if it's possible to set on that OS version.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63077687/12299030?

Comment: Yes, I posted my solution as an answer. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple way for you:

```
extension View {
   @ViewBuilder func addAccessibilityIdentifierIfVersionAvailable(identifier: String) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) { self.accessibilityIdentifier(identifier) }
        else { self } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions:

```
import SwiftUI

/// Adds AccessibilityIdentifier if it's available with the current
/// version of the SwiftUI runtime, returns the same view otherwise
struct AccessibilityIdentifier: ViewModifier {
    private let identifier: String

    /// Adds AccessibilityIdentifier if it's available with the current
    /// version of the SwiftUI runtime, returns the same view otherwise
    /// - Parameter identifier: accessibility identifier, similar to the standard SwiftUI `accessibilityIdentifier`
    init(_ identifier: String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, macOS 11.0, *) {
            content
                .accessibilityIdentifier(identifier)
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}
```

Call site:

```
Text("")
.modifier(AccessibilityIdentifier("text123"))
```

Comment: on iOS 13 you can use `.accessibility(identifier: "text123")` method to set up identifiers